# How can I motivate the community to use boinc?

Tags: community, boinc

boinc is a really nice application to use on background of a computer that can help science projects and humanity as a all.

I would like somehow to encourage people use boinc with their preferences on boinc like projects choice, cpu from 10 to 100 ,.. with their computer that will help science to move more quickly and help humanity

There are 20 million users of ubuntu if most of use boinc , this will increase the speed of science projets

.. and if other people from other operating systems use as also like mac,windows,.. and other open source like debian,.. this would even speed more science

and now anyone can win also a prize , joining a project management like http://boincstats.com/ and there is more 2 web sites

How can i get ubuntu users and ubuntu community to know and use boinc application?

Comment: You could start by having a PPA containing a release for 11.10 and 12.04...

Comment: @detly Boinc client and manager are already packaged and distributed in the repos, no need for more packages.

Comment: @BrunoPereira - My mistake! I was looking for PPAs.

Answer (score 2):

Boinc projects are great. The only way to get more people involved is to spread the word. Get involved in forums, find out if there is a Linux Users Group in your area. Talk to anyone and everyone who will listen. I work at a public university and I have gotten the Computer Science department involved. Another thing you may try is going to a public library or community center. Many of them offer free computer classes. Maybe you could be a guest speaker and just spend a few minutes introducing people to boinc or other open source projects. Write letters. Do whatever it is that you are good at to share the positive uses of this technology. :)

Comment: it would be nice more universities would join boinc application.thanks for your input i appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I am working at the moment in a [Juju Charm](https://juju.ubuntu.com/) for Boinc that automates it's deployment and configuration on the cloud.

Its still almost nothing but will make things easier for users interested in using Boinc. Have a look [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+bug/943481).

Besides that I know that Boinc has been receiving [a lot of heat from Jorge Castro](http://www.jorgecastro.org/2012/02/29/using-the-cloud-for-boinc-and-folding-at-home/) on his page, that is a very good thing.

Ubuntu is the perfect platform for deploying Boinc and the sheer amount of tools and the introduction of it as a charm ready to be deployed will make it much attractive.

If you would like to give a hand, or know someone that can give a hand (I have been lazy lazy lazy with it for personal reasons) please feel free to contact me using my email address on the users page.

Comment: i am just a user of ubuntu i do not known anything about computer science therefore at this stage i can not help you in that way.. hope you can find someone who can help you to your project